# Work with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, bootstrapvalidator

i am using codeignter framework and i want to validate field using bootstrap validator.How i make a regular expression.I am usign bootstrap validator.

Example 1:I want to validate age field in which only allow numeric value.But i enter .(Dot or decimal) This is also consider true which is wrong.
I want age like this:

```
Success Scenario Examples:
16  ,

  20 ,  50  , 60 
    Wrong Scenario Examples:
    16.5   ,  20.5 ,   25.5

    I want this will not consist of decimal point.
Here is my code:
professional_age: {
                validators: {
                    lessThan: {
                        value: 100,
                        inclusive: true,
                        message: 'The ages has to be less than or equal to 100'
                    },
                    greaterThan: {
                        value: 15,
                        inclusive: true,
                        message: 'The ages has to be greater than or equals to 15'
                    }
                }
            }
```

Example 2:
I want email regular expression:

```
These are success scenario:
zainqureshi55@gmail.com

These are wrong scenario:
zain@gmail45.com
zain@45gmail.com
zain@gmail.
Please how we make regular expression:
```

Example 3:I want a regular expression.In which alphabet and numeric value allowed.One alphabet is must.

```
This is success scenario:
123456d
123d5456
a25d852e
This is wrong scenario:
11233658
```

Comment: So, what regular expressions have you tried so far?

Comment: *In this field one character is must.* Err. what? Please also share your expression.

Comment: Any lenght with a-Z0-9? If you did not find that when you searched for it, please show me what you searched for

Comment: Age = `\d{1,2}`. What about email, there are many variants in Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex can be so:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z\d]+)$
```

Positive Lookahead tests that at least one char is present

[**demo and some explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/Sf3yWY/2)

Comment: I edit my question in which i add 2 more example help me how i sove these

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a positive look ahead. This checks if the string contains a certain regex.

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]*$
```

Explained:

```
^                 // Start of the string
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])    // Does it have a character?
[a-zA-Z\d]*       // The rest should be alphanumeric
$                 // End of the string
```

A longer explanation and examples can be found at https://regexr.com/3hrgl

Comment: i add 2 more examples plefafse help me how i solve these